# Routing clears the form's submitted data

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-forms

It is a registration form. Users submits the data through form. The Submitted data is then displayed in view. but when we route to users page the list disappears. May be because the component reloads. How could this be made to work. so that the data remains [image: Step 1] 
[image: step 2]

// app.module.ts

```
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Capitalize } from './capitalize.pipe';
import { FilterPipe } from './filter.pipe';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { ListComponent } from './list/list.component'
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegistrationComponent } from './registration/registration.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { InputDataService } from './services/input-data.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
  { path: 'users', component: ListComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Capitalize,
    FilterPipe,
    ListComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [ InputDataService ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

// app.component.html

```
<section class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div>    
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Brand</a>
      </div>  
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/registration">Registration</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/users">Users</a></li>                    
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

// app.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { IPersonModel } from '../interface/person-model';

// input data service which adds and provides data to view
@Injectable()
export class InputDataService {
  public personArr;
  personDetails: IPersonModel = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    address: '',
    date: '',
    chosenCourse: ''
  };

  getPersonData() {
    return this.personDetails;
  }

  setPersonData(obj: IPersonModel) {
    this.personDetails.name = obj.name;
    this.personDetails.email = obj.email;
    this.personDetails.address = obj.address;
    this.personDetails.chosenCourse = obj.chosenCourse;

  }

  constructor() { }

}
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker to reproduce?

Comment: sorry i dont know how to do that. can the code be added here

Comment: use the [**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit) to create one. `new->Angular` will give you all skeleton needed. add your code there and make it working. I can debug from there on. else team viewer so i can debug

Comment: ok hang on. let me try

Comment: its giving import error. plunkr not found. let try again

Comment: sorry still giving the same error. any other way i can share this code with you

Comment: when you are redirecting between routes the page is re rendered and you will get a empty page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156191/discussion-between-aravind-and-pepelearnscode).

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: The best way to share information between components is with services. You can follow the documentation tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

1) Create a service class (something like 'RegisteredUserService') and decorate it with `@Injectable`.

2) Use the service class to store and retrieve registered user information.

3) In your app.module.ts, you need to provide your service throughout your app by adding it to `providers` like so: `providers: [RegisteredUserService]`. This creates one shared instance of your service that your components can access.

4) You can access the service in any of your components by injecting it into the component's constructor like so: `constructor(protected service: RegisteredUserService){}`

From looking at the list of components in your app.module.ts, I would say that you should inject the service into your RegistrationComponent and ListComponent. When you submit the form data in RegistrationComponent, it should add a user in your service. Then in your ListComponent, you should be getting and displaying the list of users information from your service.

Comment: that is exactly what I did. But it still clears the data. I wanted someone to take look at my code. I can share it via teamviewer. let me know please if you can help with that

Comment: Update your app.module.ts code on your post. It doesn't look like you have a service. You're also not using providers in your app module. Paste your service code as well

Comment: would that be enough

Comment: i was suggesting team viewer so that you can view any and all the code

Comment: Its a start. Making a plunkr or linking a GitHub repo is a more common thing to do if you want someone to look at your whole project.

Comment: i never used plunkr before. and there are around 49 files in the whole app. what i find problem with apps like plunkr and stackblitz is that you have to reduce your app first and make it workbale as well. you just cant upload folder straight up. team viewer is most easier option among these

Comment: i can link a github repo. i didnt see that option at first

Comment: did you find whats going on